# Assertion Failed <0 <= i && i < <int>vv.size<>> in unknown function, file src\matrix.cpp, line 912

Tags: c++

First of all, i'm to new to the site (but i read and cacth info from it since a long time yet :D) so sorry if i'll make some error in structuring the question...and most important, i'm new to programming (ok not new, but i started 6 months ago)..
anyway, this is the code (the interested part):

```
extern DWORD miothread3 (LPDWORD lpdwParam)
{

Mat epsilon(dest);
Mat finale;
Mat *super;
int ratio = 3;
int lowThreshold;
int kernel_size = 3;
int i = 0;
CvConvexityDefect convessione;
vector<vector<Point> > contorni;
vector<Vec4i> gerarchia;
Mat hull;

while(1)
{
    Canny(epsilon, finale, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );
    findContours(finale, contorni, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    convexHull(contorni, hull);
}
return 0;
}
```

when i run it, i got the assertion in title ("Assertion Failed `<0 <= i && i < <int>vv.size<>>` in unknown function, file src\matrix.cpp, line 912") and if i comment the line of `convexHull(contorni, hull);` it does work...
i really cannot figure out what's the problem...so, if someone could help, would be lovable!:)

thank you in advance, best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That assertion is due to the code trying to access an invalid index of the `contorni` object (see line 937 in the current [source code)](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp). I suspect this is ultimately due to passing an invalid `contorni` object into the `convexHull()` function, perhaps an empty vector. Normally, I would expect the function to check and reject invalid input although I don't know enough about openCV to know whether the function it requires valid input or not (the [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull) doesn't mention it one way or the other).

To avoid this error I would explicitly check the input to convexHull() and/or findContours() to ensure it is valid and abort or do something appropriate if it isn't.

Comment: thank you so much, i finally reach up the conclusion...the fact is that the convexHull function take in input a vector, meanwhile the findContours takes a vector of vector, so now the problem will be transform "contorni" (a vector of vector) into a vector...does anyone know something?:D anyway, really thank you! :)

Comment: I came across http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html which may be useful to you.